# Delphi->DBGrid->ado

Tags: delphi, sql-server, dbgrid

Есть у меня DBGIRD который отображает таблицу из бд через хранимую процедуру по запросу на кнопку.

Но есть проблема, у меня есть кнопка "добавить" новую запись в таблицу, после того как я добавляю новую запись, DBGrid обновляется, запись новую видно но синий курсор должен остаться на месте, а он после каждого обновления переезжает на первую строчку.

Вопрос, как сделать обновление DBGrid но при этом чтоб курсор не уходил, а оставался на той же позиции.

Код кнопки добавить: где MainRegData - форма

```
MainRegData.ADOStoredProc1.Close;
MainRegData.ADOStoredProc1.ExecProc;
MainRegData.ADOStoredProc1.Active:=true;
```

[image: Встали на определенную строчку]
[image: Добавляем запись]
[image: После добавления должно остаться на строчке 7,но курсор уходит на первую строчку]

Answer (score 1):

До закрытия DataSet'а сохранять значение первичного ключа, а после переоткрытия вызывать Locate

**UPD**

Пример для простейшего случая, когда ПК из одного столбца - ID.

Насколько я понял, MainRegData - имя вашего `TDadaModule`

```
procedure MainRegData.refreshGrid
var
  SavedID: Variant;
begin
  SavedID := ADOStoredProc1['ID']; // подставить имя столбца PK
  ADOStoredProc1.DisableControls;
  ADOStoredProc1.Close;
  ADOStoredProc1.ExecProc;
  ADOStoredProc1.Active:=true;
  ADOStoredProc1.Locate('ID', SavedID, []); // и сюда тоже
  ADOStoredProc1.EnableControls;
end
```

Comment: Герман спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы дать элементарный пример, как это можно сделать? Если я вас правильно понял, чтобы вызвать Locate, мне нужно вызвать его в  MainRegData.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Locate(),в скобках указать ключ, но при этом Locate нужно объявить? 'function Locate (const KeyFields: String; const KeyValues: Variant; Options: TLocateOptions) : Boolean;' Хорошо, а как сохранять первичный ключ ?!

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, все получилось!!!